# How to check if two convex polyhedrons intersect with each other in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, intersection

I'm working on a problem that need to randomly generate and put convex polyhedrons into a cube/cylinder container at randomly chosen points without overlapping. I'm using [three.js](/questions/tagged/three.js) to get a graphic output.

[A demo.](http://ryeyao.tk/convex-polyhedron-gen-js/)

> While putting a polyhedron, how to check whether it intersects with other polyhedrons?

The convex polyhedron involved is simply tetrahedron or hexahedron and is constructed using THREE.ConvexGeometry. As I need a precise check, bounding box is not enough, I just use it to make sure two polyhedrons are not intersected.

I've done a lot research and found many complicated theories and methods, what I need is to get a Boolean result that tells if there exists an intersection between two convex polyhedrons. [SAT (Separating Axis Theorem)](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/) in `3D` is good enough, but `Three.js` doesn't seem to be capable of doing this. Can anyone tell me how to do this kind of check in a simple way or just explain how to do it with SAT in 3D?

Comment: Yo want accurate, you could put both objects into an object and compare both vertices , normals polygons positions on everyframe? you will need to loop through each vertices over and over and maybe add just a little bit of room so it dont have to be exact

Comment: There is no need to be precise on every frame, I just need to check at the moment a polygon is created. When an intersection is found, I need it to be certain. I am sure that [SAT](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/) can do this in both 2d and 3d, you may check it out. @Careen

Comment: But how can I make sure that the new mesh doesn't intersect with existing ones? Even if the new random position and all vertices of the polygon to be created are not in one of the existing polygons, edges of polygon still have chance to intersect other objects. @Careen

Comment: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry- you have all the atributes to check against for any interception, when creating loop through all verts faces etc and check or even use boundary box first...if that returns true than do the calculations to determine if interception is true then loop through everything in 3d space

Comment: give a picture of a scenario you have please....

Comment: http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I've edited the question to add a demo link. I used bounding sphere to accomplish this. @Careen

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @gaitat !  I've found what I need in `Static Object Intersections`. if you post an answer I'll accept it. And thank you @Careen for your patient with my bad english expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html. Even though the site is from 2011 the intersection algorithms have not changed in the last years. From the demo it seems that once the polyhedrons are placed in the cube, they don't move. So the SAT algorithm would not be the best solution as it is used for moving polyhedra.

Answer (score 0):

The Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi is a powerful algorithm that allow to measure distance and check for intersection between convex polyhedrons. Still I believe that it is better to use on simple polyhedron otherwise the computation in the support function might take some time. A possible drawback is that you need to have functions able to measure the distance between a point and another point/segment/triangle, I do not know if some are available in three.js.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm